# How can I get rid of these vertical lines in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I remove these vertical lines? - macOS

Edit: Not the best screenshot (the vertical line on the far right)

[image]

I've added in settings.json:

```
"editor.rulers": [],
```

But doesn't change anything.

Comment: Disable the setting: `Editor > Guides: Indentation`.

Comment: @Mark still there